# How many maximum number of thread groups we can run in parallel in JMeter latest version 5.6.2?

Tags: jmeter

I want to create a test suit in which want to execute more than 500 thread groups in parallel in JMeter.
Can I do it? Are there any specific calculations (related to the system configuration) or standards via which we can decide?
Can I achieve this with the CPU:2GHz and RAM: 16 GB?
Any specific system requirements are there?

I want to run the minimum 500 thread groups parallel in JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need 500 [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) you you rather mean 500 threads (virtual users)?

In both cases the maximum number is very high, something like [2,147,483,647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647)

However there are certain limitations:

1. In case of Thread Groups they normally should represent logical groups of business users (anonymous, authenticated, administrators, read-only, etc.). And I doubt that you really need 500 of them
2. In case of threads (virtual users) the limit would be something like [65535](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65,535) per JMeter engine (however it depends on network protocol, operating system, number of network interfaces, etc.). If you need more - most probably you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter).

Thread Group itself doesn't consume much resources, but how much resources does thread (virtual user) consume - it's a big question mark and it depends on the nature of your test mainly and you should rather measure how many users your JMeter instance can simulate for particular your test scenario. 500 users shouldn't be a problem given you follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)